# How to push or update data with emberfire?

Tags: firebase, ember.js, firebase-realtime-database, ember-data

**Edit: See solution at the end**

My guess was to put the model (in my case 'user') inside => type, but then it'll say "Assertion failed, you need to pass a model ..."

I do have a user.js in app/models

here's an excerpt from the router (after login function)

```js
self.store.push({
                data: {
                    id: data.currentUser.uid,
                    type: 'user',
                    attributes: {
                        displayName: data.currentUser.displayName,
                        email: data.currentUser.email,
                        photoURL: data.currentUser.photoURL,
                        firebaseUID: data.currentUser.uid,
                        rank: "scorer",
                        status: "active",
                        loginCount: 0,
                        provider: provider,
                        timestamp: new Date().getTime()
                    }
                }
            });
```

and here's my model (user.js in app/models)

```js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  displayName: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  photoURL: DS.attr('string'),
  firebaseUID: DS.attr('string'),
  rank: DS.attr('string'),
  status: DS.attr('string'),
  loginCount: DS.attr('string'),
  provider: DS.attr('string'),
  timestamp: DS.attr('number')
});
```

Please help :( thanks everyone in advance!

**Edit => Solution that worked:** If you do a createRecord and match the "id:" attribute, it will update the record with the same id (will work if you specified your own id). However, I'm not sure yet how to update a record if you let the system generate an ID for you. I assume that you would have to extract the ID first. But I haven't tested that idea yet. If someone would be so kind to test it, that'll be awesome.

Comment: Could you post more of the error trace?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, here's what I got from the console

`rsvp.js:27 Uncaught EmberError {stack: "Error: Assertion Failed: You need to pass a model …(http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:85226:38)", description: undefined, fileName: undefined, lineNumber: undefined, message: "Assertion Failed: You need to pass a model name to the store's adapterFor method", …}`

Comment: @runspired, after posting the error trace, I went ahead and tried donleche's solution and matching the "id" attr. And it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of pushing the raw data, create a model and run its `save` method.

```
var user = this.store.createRecord('user', {
    displayName: data.currentUser.displayName,
    // set more properties here
})
user.save()
```

This way, Emberfire and Ember Data can do their thing and ensure the data is formatted correctly. Also see

- https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md#5-save-data
- https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/
- https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/

Comment: The user did not ask how to create a new record, but how to update the state for an existing one or push an existing record into the store.

Comment: It is the same process for updating or pushing existing records. You call `save()` on the model and Emberfire will push the changes. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: this will work if you match the "id:" of the record, thanks a lot!